# Upload File Codeigniter,can't detect variabel

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to make upload image function on Codeigniter. but, when I trying to insert the image to the database. the variable can't be detected.

**Here is my controller :**

```html
public function registrasi() {
 //VALIDATION
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email|is_unique[tb_m_user.email]');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim|min_length[3]|matches[konfirmasi_password]');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('konfirmasi_password', 'Retype Password', 'required|trim|matches[password]');

  if($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
   $this->session->set_flashdata('fail' , 'Registration Failed! Please Try Again');
   $this->load->view('auth/registrasi');
  }else{
   //INSERT TO DATABASE
   $username  = $this->input->post('username');
   $email   = $this->input->post('email');
   $password  = password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
   $pict   = $_FILES['pict'];
     
    //LIBRARY UPLOAD CONFIG
    $config['upload_path']  = '/assets/dist/foto_validasi';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
    $config['file_name']  = date('ymd');
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
      
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('pict')){
     echo "Upload Failed"; 
    }else{
     $pict = $this->upload->data('file_name');
    }

   $data = [
    'user_name'   => $username,
    'email'       => $email,
    'password'  => $password,
    'role'        => 'pengguna',
    'img'       => $pict,
    'status_aktivasi' => 'tidak aktif',
    'created_by'  => 'SYSTEM',
   ];

    $this->m_auth->registrasi($data, 'tb_m_user');
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success' , 'Registration Successful! Please Login');
    Redirect('Auth/login');
   }
  }

  public function login() {
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

   if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
    $this->load->view('auth/login');
   }else{
    $this->postlogin();
   }
  }
```

**Here is my form View :**

```html
<?= form_open_multipart('Auth/registrasi'); ?>
<div class="border-top mt-3">
            <div class="ml-2">
            <label class="mt-2">Upload Kartu Identitas</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
           <input type="file" class="form-control" placeholder="Upload Foto Identitas" name="pict">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <span class="fas fa-file-image"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <small class="text-danger"><?= form_error('foto') ?></small>
        </div>
 <?= form_close(); ?>
```

> Here is the error : [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxe4R.png)

---

---

I even tried to change the variabel from:

> $pict = $this->upload->data('file_name');
>
> 'img'          => $pict,

to :

> $pict2 = $this->upload->data('file_name');
>
> 'img'          => $pict2,

---

> but it gets another error :[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAmvT.png)

Comment: The error message says _upload failed_, so the `$pict` variable is undefined. Do you want the upload feature to be mandatory or optional?

Comment: i want it to be mandatory

Comment: check your field name correct or not  you are posting file name in name="pict" and getting image name as if(!$this->upload->do_upload('foto')){

Comment: oh yeah, it was unedited sorry. but it was already done on my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the upload feature to be required, you could modify the codes like this :

```php
public function registrasi() {
    //VALIDATION
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email|is_unique[tb_m_user.email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim|min_length[3]|matches[konfirmasi_password]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('konfirmasi_password', 'Retype Password', 'required|trim|matches[password]');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('fail' , 'Registration Failed! Please Try Again');
        $this->load->view('auth/registrasi');
    }else{
        //INSERT TO DATABASE
        $username   = $this->input->post('username');
        $email      = $this->input->post('email');
        $password   = password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $pict       = $_FILES['pict'];

        //LIBRARY UPLOAD CONFIG
        $config['upload_path']      = '/assets/dist/foto_validasi';
        $config['allowed_types']    = 'jpg|png';
        $config['file_name']        = date('ymd');
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('foto')){
            echo "Upload Failed"; 
            $this->session->set_flashdata('fail', $this->upload->display_errors() );
            redirect( 'auth/registrasi' );
        }else{
            $pict = $this->upload->data('file_name');
            $data = [
                'user_name'   => $username,
                'email'       => $email,
                'password'  => $password,
                'role'        => 'pengguna',
                'img'         => $pict,
                'status_aktivasi'   => 'tidak aktif',
                'created_by'        => 'SYSTEM',
            ];

            $this->m_auth->registrasi($data, 'tb_m_user');
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success' , 'Registration Successful! Please Login');
            Redirect('Auth/login');
        }
    }
}
```

The `$this->upload->display_errors()` code will display the error message on the uploaded file that does not meet the requirements, so if the file is not uploaded then the registration data will not be saved.

Comment: it doesn't show any errors. it just redirected back to the registration page without any following errors. and the data didn't even go to the database

Comment: I've updated the codes, changed `$this->load->view('auth/registrasi'); ` to `redirect( 'auth/registrasi' );`, this should show the session upload message after the redirect

Comment: yeah, it worked!. apparently my upload_path was invalid. I forgot to put  'dot' before the '/'. it has to be like this './assets/dist/foto_validasi'

Answer (score 0):

> Change the post field name as if(!$this->upload->do_upload(**'pict'**)){

```
if(!$this->upload->do_upload('pict')){ // You should change this
```

Answer (score 0):

size attribute should be there in input field

```
<input type="file" size="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Upload Foto Identitas" name="pict">
```